# Who is Lord in Islam?

Tags: arabic, allah

> قَالَ رَبُّنَا الَّذِي أَعْطَىٰ كُلَّ شَيْءٍ خَلْقَهُ ثُمَّ هَدَىٰ
>
> He said: "Our Lord is He Who gave to each (created) thing its
>   [particular] form and nature [through which it is distinguished from
>   another thing], then gave (it) guidance." (Taahaa:50)

Lord is Allah (الرحمن الرحيم) here.  However in the Bible and Torah, there are different words.  There is **Lord** which is **Adonai** and is the literal "lord" or ruler.  There is also **LORD** which is **YAHUAH** which is the personal name of the God.  Why is the translation here from "رَبُّنَا" to Lord?

Comment: I can see the validity of your question, but I don't think there is a definitive answer. It seems to me that the translator refers to the common meaning of the word, not the particular literals from the Bible and Torah. However, I don't have any proof of this claim. Only the translator can confirm or deny.

Comment: @HosamAly Ultimately I think you're right.  However I had this question with nobody to ask.  The question may not be a good fit for SE in hindsight.

Comment: Allah is lord of the lords (رب الأرباب), but here it is Ibrahim peace be upon him that is talking and from what he is saying it is clear that by "our lord" he means only Allah.

Comment: @owari That's Moses talking, not Ibrahim (pbut). You can see it in context here: http://quran.com/20/49-50

Comment: @HosamAly, yes you are right, my mistake. Thanks brother. Godspeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular Ayah, the word "ربنا" (Rabbuna) is (most probably) used as an adjective, not a noun. So a translation should be referring to "Our Lord" as in "The One who created us, who cares for us and our livelihood."

(Excuse my poor English translation; please improve it if you can.)

Answer (score 1):

It's really a matter of translation here as Hosam Aly stated. In hindi I have heard same verse with different word like  'Rab', 'Malik', etc All mean the same.

It may refer to some other person as you have stated in Bible or Torah, but in Quran, it does mean the God Almighty.

Answer (score -1):

The word lord* is not correct word to be used in the translation(in my opinion) ,thats an english word with pagan roots
According to the Oxford Dictionary of English, the etymology of the word can be traced back to the Old English word hlāford which originated from hlāfweard meaning "loaf-ward" or "bread keeper", reflecting the Germanic tribal custom of a chieftain providing food for his followers.[3] The appellation "lord" is primarily applied to men, while for women the appellation "lady" is used.[citation needed] However, this is no longer universal: the Lord of Mann, a title currently held by the Queen of the United Kingdom, and female

It should not be used in translation of QUR'AN (again in my opinion)

Comment: I suggest you to look here:[How do I write a good answer?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)